# WPF: How implement autoscroll to a row in one datagrid based on user selection in another datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm a bit of a noob working with datagrids in WPF and am struggling to get my head around an issue. I've reviewed the existing questions but haven't found anything that nails what I am after.

I am trying to implement a feature in my wpf application that autoscrolls to a row on a datagrid if the user selects a row in a second datagrid. The scenario is this: I have a main datagrid that displays log file entries found in a collection of log files. A second datagrid shows any errors logged in the collection of log files. If the user selects an error (ie a row) on the Errors datagrid, I want to autoscroll the main datagrid to the row that corresponds to that error.

Both datagrids are bound to two observablecollections in my ViewModel. Also in the ViewModel I keep track of the row id for each of the errors.

What is the cleanest/easiest way to implement scrolling to a row in a datagrid based on a selection in another datagrid? Can I do this just in xaml or will I need to fiddle with my ViewModel?

Here is the first datagrid showing the collection of errors:

```
<TabItem Header="Error List">
                <DataGrid x:Name="ErrorDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxHeight="300" DataGridRow.Selected="DataGrid_Selected">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sequence" Binding="{Binding DGSequenceNum}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Timestamp}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Level" Binding="{Binding Level}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}" Width="auto"/>                        
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
</TabItem>
```

Here is the second datagrid showing the full collection of log entries:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntry}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxHeight="800"  Width="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sequence" Binding="{Binding DGSequenceNum}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding Timestamp}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Level" Binding="{Binding Level}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}" Width="auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meta" Binding="{Binding Meta}" Width="auto"/>                
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Meta}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

 </DataGrid>
```

Any recommendations you might have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to find the data item in the Log items collection.
From The DataGrid you have to get the DataGridRow that contains the item as its visual container (through `DataGrid.ItemsContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem ).

It returns a formal DependencyObject which is a `DataGridRow` by runtime type. Cast it to FramworkElement or DataGridRow  and call `BringIntoView` on it. And you're done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview